# Android's Google services error, something with Magisk and Zygote SIGABRT (SIGNAL 6)

Tags: android, google-play-services, hide, system, root

---

Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/vili_global/vili:13/RKQ1.211001.001/V14.0.3.0.TKDMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-03-13 20:40:36.559419377+0500
Process uptime: 1s
ZygotePid: 475716748
Cmdline: zygote64
pid: 26439, tid: 26439, name: main  >>> zygote64 <<<
uid: 0
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000006747  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007ff403a160
x4  6b736967616d2e2f  x5  6b736967616d2e2f  x6  6b736967616d2e2f  x7  74656b636f732f6b
x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007da603ecb0  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000007da60b37c8
x12 00000000003e7d0a  x13 00000039c066fd89  x14 000f18b6748383d4  x15 0000000034155555
x16 0000007da611ea80  x17 0000007da60f7450  x18 0000007db67f2000  x19 0000000000006747
x20 0000000000006747  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 0000007cf8a76451
x24 0c32df055fa9d697  x25 0000007ceaea6164  x26 0000007cf8a9cb68  x27 0000007ff403a528
x28 0000000000000008  x29 0000007ff403a1e0
lr  0000007da60a4748  sp  0000007ff403a140  pc  0000007da60a4774  pst 0000000000001000
backtrace:
#00 pc 000000000008d774  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168) (BuildId: 449f781894033dce6346794a1ee593e0)
#01 pc 0000000000009554  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted)
#02 pc 0000000000001f64  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted)
#03 pc 0000000000001da8  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted)
#04 pc 0000000000001d20  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted)
#05 pc 0000000000001ae8  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted)
#06 pc 000000000002fa58  /system/lib64/libzygisk.so (BuildId: b4c7d85e83f5b20e40d07cc293f9467b13eb1132)
#07 pc 000000000002fbdc  /system/lib64/libzygisk.so (BuildId: b4c7d85e83f5b20e40d07cc293f9467b13eb1132)
#08 pc 000000000002ff00  /system/lib64/libzygisk.so (BuildId: b4c7d85e83f5b20e40d07cc293f9467b13eb1132)
#09 pc 0000000000031b14  /system/lib64/libzygisk.so (BuildId: b4c7d85e83f5b20e40d07cc293f9467b13eb1132)
#10 pc 000000000012e204  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+356)
#11 pc 0000000000209b68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+2152) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#12 pc 0000000002413e66  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (com.android.internal.os.Zygote.forkAndSpecialize+8)
#13 pc 0000000002022048  /memfd:jit-zygote-cache (deleted) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.processCommand+1528)
#14 pc 000000000020a2b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+4016) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#15 pc 0000000002417c32  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteServer.runSelectLoop+610)
#16 pc 000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#17 pc 00000000024166d6  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+602)
#18 pc 0000000000210c00  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+576) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#19 pc 000000000027b4ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+240) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#20 pc 0000000000617350  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgsart::ArtMethod*(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+452) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#21 pc 000000000061783c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+96) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#22 pc 00000000004fec68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+600) (BuildId: 6e90d86ae3f84492e7ba2f9ed464c338)
#23 pc 00000000000c0c04  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 549d65a3f3d9a412c8f7267b58f3cbce)
#24 pc 00000000000cd80c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vectorandroid::String8 const&, bool)+924) (BuildId: 549d65a3f3d9a412c8f7267b58f3cbce)
#25 pc 0000000000002610  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1464) (BuildId: 0392f54b3dffeef9b6cad14b6f0bdd45)
#26 pc 00000000000859b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+100) (BuildId: 449f781894033dce6346794a1ee593e0)
[Magisk modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymg5x.jpg)

idk how i started getting this error.After encountering this I updated Magisk to 27.0 and rebooted phone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.